# Linked list addition (of total size n) and reversion of last k nods at order of n

Tags: algorithm, doubly-linked-list

I am looking at this challenge:

> Given are numbers *m* and *p*, which both may be as large as 250000. The next *m* lines have one of the following commands:
>
> - `APPEND y`, which adds `y` to the end of our list (queue)
> - `ROTATE`, which reverses the *p* last elements of the list. If the list has fewer than *p* elements, it reverses all of the elements of the list.
>
> Our job is to print the list after all commands have been executed.
>
> A brute force approach is to reverse the array manually, which would have a complexity of *O(pm)*, but you are required to implement it with a complexity of *O(m)*.

I have thought about using a doubly linked list, and I am quite sure it would work, but I could not complete my answer.

## Example

#### Input

```
8 3

APPEND 1
APPEND 2
APPEND 3
APPEND 4
ROTATE
APPEND 5
APPEND 6
ROTATE
```

#### Output

```
1 4 3 6 5 2
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure who is "we" and who is "you", and also what the question is. Can you maybe provide an example, as code or pseudocode?

Comment: Well, looks like a nice challenge. What's you question, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Make a struct with two pointers of prev and next which points to next or previous element in the list (is null for the first and last element).
Whenever append is called, simply make a new node and assign pointers for it and the previous node.
We must keep the node of K numbers before the end of the list, or first node if the list size is less than m already, say node L
When reverse is called, for the element before L, assign the next pointer to L+p, and for L+1,L+2,....,L+p change the state of node's boolean so that you have changed the orientation while L moves forward.

Comment: I meant each node has a boolean in it called state, which states wheater the next pointer is next, or prev (depending on that whether this node is a slice of array that must be rotated.
using this, it is guaranteed that the algorithm is from O(m). I think it must work.
But there's only one problem I cannot handle:
While already moving L and changing the state, if another ROTATE is called what should we do?

Comment: Given the problem statement quoted, the title of this post looks an XY-problem - there are bound to be other approaches than using a doubly linked list. What if you take an array of *p* elements, keep track of *head* and *tail*, switching a) roles and direction of appends or b) "sign" of offsets, printing every element that is about to be overwritten (not to the letter of *print the list **after** all commands*, granted).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea of a doubly linked list is correct. To make it work you need to step away from prev/next notions, but just keep track of the potential 2 neighbours a node may have, without any indication of direction (prev/next).

Your doubly linked list will have a head and a tail -- that must stay. And you are right to also maintain a reference to the node that is currently the start node of the "k last elements" (or fewer when there are not that many elements in the list). Keep that updated whenever you add a node. In order to know in which direction to move that reference, also maintain a reference to the node that precedes it.

Then, when a reversal needs to be performed, it is a matter of swapping the references (and back-references) to the head and tail of that "k last element" sublist. Don't go over the whole sublist to change links between each pair of consecutive nodes. By removing the idea of prev/next, you can just leave those "internal" links as they are. Whenever you need to iterate through the list, you will always know which side you are coming from (i.e. what the "previous" node was), and so you can derive which of the neighbours must be the "next" one.

Here is an implementation of that idea in JavaScript. At the end of the code the algorithm is executed for the example input you have given:

```js
class Node {
    constructor(x, neighbor1=null, neighbor2=null) {
        this.x = x;
        this.neighbors = [neighbor1, neighbor2]; // No specific order...
    }
    opposite(neighbor) { 
        // Return the neighbor that is on the other side of the argument-neighbor
        return this.neighbors[1 - this.neighbors.indexOf(neighbor)];
    }
    replaceNeighbor(find, repl) {
        let i = this.neighbors.indexOf(find);
        this.neighbors[i] = repl;
    }
}

class List {
    constructor(k) {
        this.nodeCount = 0;
        this.k = k;
        // All node references are null:
        this.head = this.tail = this.tailBeforeLastK = this.headOfLastK = null;
    }
    add(x) {
        this.nodeCount++;
        let node = new Node(x, this.tail, null);
        if (this.head === null) {
            this.headOfLastK = this.head = this.tail = node;
            return;
        }
        this.tail.replaceNeighbor(null, node);
        this.tail = node;
        if (this.nodeCount > this.k) { // Move the head of the "last K" sublist 
            [this.tailBeforeLastK, this.headOfLastK] = 
                [this.headOfLastK, this.headOfLastK.opposite(this.tailBeforeLastK)]; 
        }
    }
    reverse() {
        if (this.nodeCount < 2 || this.k < 2) return;
        // Exchange the links to the start/end of the K-last sublist
        this.tail.replaceNeighbor(null, this.tailBeforeLastK);
        if (this.tailBeforeLastK) {
            this.tailBeforeLastK.replaceNeighbor(this.headOfLastK, this.tail);
            this.headOfLastK.replaceNeighbor(this.tailBeforeLastK, null);
        }
        else this.head = this.tail;
        
        // Swap
        [this.tail, this.headOfLastK] = [this.headOfLastK, this.tail];
    }
    toArray() {
        let result = [];
        for (let prev = null, node = this.head; node; [prev, node] = 
                                                      [node, node.opposite(prev)]) {
            result.push(node.x);
        }
        return result;
    }
}

// Example
let k = 3;
// null means: REVERSE, a number means: ADD <number>:
let actions = [1, 2, 3, 4, null, 5, 6, null]; 

let list = new List(k);

for (let action of actions) {
    if (action === null) list.reverse();
    else                 list.add(action);
}
console.log(list.toArray());
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. Let me implement it and check your idea.